# StreamCorruptedException during serialised object decryption (and other byte fields)

Tags: java, encryption, serialization

my software raised StreamCorruptedException during a deciphering:
My cipher is AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding and my key is obtained with PBKey Derivation method, so I need to create a salt to generate AES128 key.

My goal is to obtain a file formed in this way:

[image]

(I will delete exception management code to improve readability)
My cipher code:

```
char[] password = passwordString.toCharArray();

    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte salt[] = new byte[SALT_BYTES]; 
    random.nextBytes(salt);

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");

    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, ITERATION, AES_KEY_BITS);

    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);

    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/PKCS5Padding");

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    ObjectOutputStream objOut = null;


        fout = new FileOutputStream(PRIVATE_RING_FILENAME);

        fout.write(salt);

        byte[] ivN = cipher.getIV();
        fout.write(ivN);

        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fout, cipher);
        objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(cos);

        PrivateKeyRing prvKeyRing = new PrivateKeyRing();
        SealedObject sealedObject = new SealedObject(prvKeyRing, cipher);
        objOut.writeObject(sealedObject);

        fout.close();
        objOut.close();
        cos.close();
```

and it works without problem.

My deciphering code:

```
char[] password = passwordString.toCharArray();

    File file = new File(PRIVATE_RING_FILENAME);
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);


    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/PKCS5Padding");


    byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_BYTES];

    fin.read(salt);


    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");


    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, ITERATION, AES_KEY_BITS);

    SecretKey = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);

    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");


        byte[] ivN = new byte[AES_BYTES];
        fin.read(ivN, 0, AES_BYTES);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(ivN));

    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fin, cipher);
    ObjectInputStream objIn;
    PrivateKeyRing prvKeyRing = null;
    SealedObject sealedObject = null;
    objIn = new ObjectInputStream(cis);

    sealedObject = (SealedObject) objIn.readObject();
    prvKeyRing = (PrivateKeyRing) sealedObject.getObject(cipher);

        objIn.close();
        fin.close();
        cis.close();
```

But StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720019 occurs when system execute:

```
objIn = new ObjectInputStream(cis);
```

If I try to write the object without ciphering all works.
What do you think about? 
I read about some problem when you try to write multiple serialised object but I think this is not the case.

Comment: Why are you encrypting and decrypting twice?

Comment: For one thing, you're closing your output streams in the wrong order. Close the "innermost" one first - ideally, use try-with-resources statements instead of closing manually at all. Next you're ignoring the results of `InputStream.read` - you may not be reading as many bytes as you expect. Have you checked that `ivN` and `salt` are what you expect?

Comment: Also, what is `AES_BYTES` and have you checked it's the same as `ivn.length`?

Comment: That's not correct. You should close the *outermost* one first, otherwise you may lose data due to the final `flush()` not being possible. Try-with-resources will do that for you.

Comment: CFB doesn't require padding, try `NoPadding` (Jon, EJP and little old me, you could do worse :P ) .

Comment: CFB/PKCS5Padding is a specific request of my teacher. 

So I need to invert closing order?
1- cis
2- fin
3- obj?

I'm sure about ivn.lenght is equal to  AES_BYTES.

Answer (score 1):

This comes about because you are encrypting and decrypting twice with the same cipher. The object is first sealed with the cipher and then written to the cipher output stream, with the cipher in the state resulting from sealing the object. This does not yield a file that can be decrypted with the cipher in its initial state. You would have to unseal the object first and then read it from the stream, which is impossible. Get rid of either the cipher streams or the sealed object.

Comment: So I need to made it without using Sealed Object?
I have to write object directly right?

Comment: Correct. You need *either* the cipher streams *or* the sealed object. Not both.